# Join two diagonal vertices of a square with an outer edge?

Tags: diagrams

[image]

This is the case,I'm sorry for the drafty picture

Comment: [Welcome to tex.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Note that people usually don't respond to post unless you show your effort dealing with the problem, e.g. showing your source code. I made an exception because the code is trivial and you are new to the site. Hope it helps.

Comment: OK thank you Ondrian. Now I know so next time I'll provide the code too

Answer (score 7):

You can use TikZ to make the picture. You can `scale` it to required size. See the code below.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]

    \draw [thick] rectangle (1,1);
    \draw [thick] (0,1) -- (1,0);
    \draw [thick] (0,1) .. controls (1,2) and (2,1) .. (1,0);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Another TikZ example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \newcommand*{\OutAngle}{60}
  \newcommand*{\ArcMax}{1.2}
  \draw
    (0, 0) rectangle (1, 1)
    (0, 1) to[out=\OutAngle, in=135]
    (\ArcMax, \ArcMax) to[out=-45, in=90-\OutAngle]
    (1, 0) -- cycle
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The exiting angle at the top can be configured via macro `\OutAngle`. The maximal distance of the arc from the origin can be specified via macro `\ArcMax`, which is uses as *x* and *y* coordinate for the farthest point.

Answer (score 3):

`Pstricks` also easily yields good results:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt, x11names]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-poly, pst-eucl, pstricks-add}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\psset{unit = 2cm, dimen = m}
\begin{pspicture*}
\providecommand{\PstPolygonNode}{%
\psdots[dotstyle = o, dotsize=4pt, linecolor=LightSteelBlue3, fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=LightSteelBlue3](1;\INode)}
\PstSquare[PolyName=A]
\uput[ul](A2){A} \uput[ur](A1){B}
\uput[dr](A4){C} \uput[dl](A3){D}
\ncline[nodesep=2pt]{A2}{A4}
\pnode[0.25,0.25](A0){O}
\pstArcOAB[linecolor=LightSteelBlue3]{O}{A4}{A2}
 \end{pspicture*}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Metapost](http://tug.org/metapost.html) provides another alternative; here I've used `lualatex` and `luamplib` but you can use plain `mpost` instead if you don't use `lualatex` yet.

[image]

I've shown four different ways to get a curve between the vertices.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
u := 3cm;
path B; B = unitsquare scaled u;
draw B;
draw point 3 of B -- point 1 of B;
draw point 3 of B .. controls (u,2u) and (2u,u) .. point 1 of B withcolor .6 red;
draw point 3 of B .. controls point 2 of B      .. point 1 of B withcolor .6 blue;
draw point 3 of B {dir 60}                      .. point 1 of B withcolor .6 green;
draw point 3 of B {dir -20}                     .. point 1 of B dashed withdots;
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```